# How can you add custom buttons and text to an android navigation? (Logged in as X)

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I'm creating an android app and making a custom top navbar for it. I am using a res/menu xml file to do this.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to add a button with text on it that says "Log In" when the user is not logged in and "You are logged in as X" when they are logged in. I have not been able to find a way to have text buttons however.

After searching online I have, surprisingly, been unable to find many guides or discussion on the topic. The only options I ahve found are "Group", "Menu", "Switch" and "Search" which all seem to have pre-defined pictures.

Is there a way I can add custom text buttons to an android nav bar?

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try below code : 

     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_menu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/Logout"

                    />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Toolbar instead of default Action bar

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" > 

             <RelativeLayout
              .
              .
              .
             </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```